# Internal path length of red black tree

Tags: c++, recursion, red-black-tree

I am working on a homework problem which asks us to find the Internal path length of a red black tree. This is the code I have implemented so far.

```
int Tree::internalpathlength(BinTree* root_node, int curr_level){
int ipl;
if(root_node == NULL){
    return 0;
}
else if(root_node->colour == BLACK){
    ipl = (curr_level+internalpathlength(root_node->left,curr_level+1)+internalpathlength(root_node->right,curr_level+1));

}
return ipl;
}
```

I think I am missing the base case of the recursion. Can someone help me understand it better?
Thanks.

Comment: You return an uninitialized value `int ipl;` in case none of the conditions matched.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ. I fixed that. I still don't seem to be getting around the issue. I believe it has something to do with assigning root node to BLACK. I'm not sure if it is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct answer is that we do not have to check for root node's colour to be black. The internal path length should be calculated for both black and red nodes. 
 If we do not consider the red link, it means that we are considering elements connected by a red link as a two node, which is not the case.

```
int Tree::internalpathlength(BinTree* root_node, int curr_level){
    if(root_node == NULL){
    return 0;
    }
     else
      return (curr_level+internalpathlength(root_node->left,curr_level+1)+internalpathlength(root_node->right,curr_level+1));
  }
```